# Understanding how the JS engine is looping through to get the index of an array element

Tags: javascript, loops, iterator, javascript-engine

I wrote a function to output the names and real-life indexes of people waiting in a line.

```js
var line = ["Sarah", "Mike", "Bob"];

function currentLine(line) {
  if (line.length === 0) {
    document.write(`The line is currently empty.`);
  } else {

    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
      array.push(` ${line.indexOf(line[i+1])}. ${line[i]}`);
    }
    document.write(`The line is currently:` + array);
  }
}

currentLine(line);
```

When I run the function, the output is:

`The line is currently: 1. Sarah, 2. Mike, -1. Bob`

How is the JavaScript engine interpreting the loop? How is Bob -1? Last time I checked 2 + 1 = 3.

I want to fix this myself but I'm trying to understand what is going on in this seemingly straight forward loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is right in your analysis:

> > How is Bob -1? Last time I checked 2 + 1 = 3

On the third iteration of the loop, i = 2.  This line executes with i = 2:

```
line.indexOf(line[i+1])
```

So what does this say?  It says get me the element at position `(i + 1)`, which is position 3, or the *forth* element.  There is no forth element, so `line[i+1]` is `undefined`.

Pass that to the `indexOf` call and what you are saying is, find me the position of `undefined` in the `line` array.  `line` contains 'Sarah', 'Mike', and 'Bob'.  It does not contain `undefined`.

I made a small change to the `array.push` line and it works correctly now:

```
var line = ["Sarah", "Mike", "Bob"];

function currentLine(line) {
  if (line.length === 0) {
    document.write(`The line is currently empty.`);
  } else {

    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
      array.push(` ${i+1}. ${line[i]}`);
    }
    document.write(`The line is currently:` + array);
  }
}

currentLine(line);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Brandon. Computational thinking is a head trip for a newbie. It makes sense when explained so well. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `${line.indexOf(line[i+1])}` is that on the last iteration, where `i` is 2, it checks for `line[3]`. That doesn't exist so it spit's out a -1, as that is the return value of `indexOf` if something doesn't exist. Just go with this:

```
array.push(` ${i+1}. ${line[i]}`);
```

This just prints `i` + 1, instead of looking for index.

```js
var line = ["Sarah", "Mike", "Bob"];

function currentLine(line) {
  if (line.length === 0) {
    document.write(`The line is currently empty.`);
  } else {
    var array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
      console.log(line.indexOf(line[i+1])); //On last iteration, it's -1 because it's not found in the array!
      array.push(` ${i+1}. ${line[i]}`);
    }
    document.write(`The line is currently:` + array);
  }
}

currentLine(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the loop. I overcomplicated the indexing:

`${line.indexOf(line[i+1])}`

which should be:

`${[i+1]}` - is that legitimate syntax?

Also, if anyone could shed light on what my incorrect code was doing and how JS was iterating, I would greatly appreciate it.